# link to an external static library by g++

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute a cpp file named "palindrome.cpp" **using terminal** on my Macbook. This cpp file uses an external library named "libStanfordCPPLib.a" which lies under "DIRECTORY TO CPP FILE/StanfordCPPLib", also the corresponding header files of this library are in this "StanfordCPPLib" folder.
You can see the folder structure by this screenshot: [image]

My code for compiling this source code is :

```
g++-4.8 -Wall -I/Users/myName/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib -L/Users/myName/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib palindrome.cpp libStanfordCPPLib.a
```

As I understand, -I stands for the directory path where header files exist, and -L stands for the directory path where library (.a file) exists. That's why both -I and -L are the same directory path "/Users/myName/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib".

However, executing this command returns an error saying :"libStanfordCPPLib.a: No such file or directory". As is shown in the screenshot:[image]

Can anyone see why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: try executing the same command with removing the part "lib" from the library's name " StanfordCPPLib.a" or either "StanfordCPP.a" .. because as I know the linker will prefix and postfix your library name with lib before searching for it.

Comment: No, It still can't work. The error message is " error: StanfordCPP.a: No such file or directory"

Comment: Have you tried with StanfordCPPLib.a ?

Comment: Hi, I have solved this by changing LibStanfordCPPLib.a to -lStanfordCPPLib. Then it can compile

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using -lStanfordCPPLib:

```
g++-4.8 -Wall -I/Users/myName/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib -L/Users/myName/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib palindrome.cpp -lStanfordCPPLib
```

Comment: it can compile now. However I got a warning saying "ignoring file /Users/lihang/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib/libStanfordCPPLib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/lihang/Downloads/CS106B/palindrome/StanfordCPPLib/libStanfordCPPLib.a"  I 'll figure it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: The warning says that the library was build for x86 (32bit) machine. Your machine is 64bit, and hence cannot use the binary that was compiled for a 32bit. You either compile the the library yourself form source, or obtain a correct executable

Comment: That is wired, cause I can run this program on my Xcode.

Comment: Then, you might have 32bit libraries installed in the system. Good luck!